# What does "Uniform Type" mean in Adobe Illustrator (cmd-shift-X)?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, shortcuts

Today I was updating my **Adobe Illustrator** keyboard shortcuts under **Edit › Keyboard Shortcuts**.

Under **Menu Commands › Other Text**, there is a shortcut for **Uniform Type** (<kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>).

Does anyone know what this is?

In most cases, Adobe seems to consider a command to be relatively important if there is a shortcut assigned to it.

I have searched extensively online and cannot find out what **Uniform Type** means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That didn't take long.

It resets the percentage height and width of stretched text to 100.